# Питон не видит модули, не получается импортировать

Tags: python, модули

Я установил все нужные модули для проекта, они уже находятся в папке site-packages с питоном

[image: Установка модулей которых не видит IDE]

[image: Импорты которые не получаются]

Я использую python 3.9.5, 32 разрядности, после установки модулей, я перезагружал IDE, компьютер, и интерпретатор (я использую VSCode)

При запуске командная строка в IDE выдаёт это

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Programming\Python\название проекта\название .py файла", line 2, in <module>
    from Crypto.Hash import SHA512
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

Как можно увидеть по консоли, где я устанавливал модули через pip, pywin был установлен несколько раз (pypiwin32, pywin32), я пробовал "более современное решение", на похожем сайте - https://progi.pro/nevozmozhno-importirovat-modul-python-win32crypt-11627061

> Более современное решение:
> pip install pypiwin32 Это содержит файлы.whl, которые помогут установить в Windows. ответил(а) 4 месяца назад David Metcalfe

Другие модули устанавливаются и импортируются корректно, например - import ip2geotools и import tempfile

Comment: мое первое желание это ставить все это дело в [виртуальное окружение](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html). Второе - это перепроверить совместимость версий. А, третье - поставить в виртуальное окружение с `python` версией ниже чем 3.9.5 (но это ради эксперимента и более детального погружения в вопрос)

Comment: Я ставил модуль `Crypto` из пакета `pycryptodome`. Вы его не пробовали? Ну и проконтролировать что реально установлено в директории `site-packages`. Может там вообще нет модуля `Crypto`. Или, например, у меня раз модуль поставился в директорию названную маленькими буквами, а ссылаться на него требовалось по названию с большой буквы. Пришлось руками просто переименовать директорию и он заработал.

Comment: Вы пакеты устанавливали в глобальный питон, а IDE, возможно, использует virtualenv. Выполните команду `pip freeze` из консоли IDE, чтобы увидеть установленные пакеты в том окружении, которое использует IDE. Если там нет нужных, то установите их именно оттуда командами `pip install <package>`

Comment: @GrAnd https://imgur.com/a/cvx4NwE
Есть, я тоже пробовал через pycryptodome

Comment: @RomanKonoval сделал, ошибка не исправилась

Comment: @RomanKonoval https://imgur.com/a/bOHxRY6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нашёл решение проблемы, вроде (ну по крайней мере этот импорт больше не подсвечивается жёлтым в VSC и не просит починить) итак к сути:
пишем
pip install cryptohash
и заменяем from Crypto.Hash import SHA512 на from cryptohash import sha512 (в моём случае)
программу не тестировал, ещё не пофиксил другие проблемы, поэтому работоспособность программы с этим методом незнаю.

Если у вас аналогичная проблема, но не в точности похожая и вы уверенны, что установили модуль без ошибок (ошибки обычно подсвечиваются красным):
Перейдите в папку где у вас находится python.exe -> Lib -> site-packages и поиском файлов Windows пишите название проблемного модуля, если их несколько или заглавная буква отличается, найдите нужный путём проверки файлов, в моём случае я проверил файл SHA512.py (который импортировал), он оказался в обоих, но работало только с тем, который был написан маленькими буквами