# Проблема с импортом модулей

Tags: python, python-import

Собственно, сама проблема на скриншоте
Нужно как-то это дело пофиксить, может кто-нибудь подскажет как решить эту проблему?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите код и сообщения об ошибке текстом, а не картинкой. Кидать такие скриншоты не уважительно по отношению к другим участникам.

Answer (score 0):

Перейдите в каталог с помощью терминала либо командной строки (cmd запустите от имени администратора), например

```
C:\Python39\Scripts\
```

Выполните установку пакетов, командами

```
pip install requests
pip install lxml
```

Comment: благодарю за помощь, устанавливаю пакеты))))

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь что у вас установлены пакеты, если пакеты уже установлены, а проблема не решилась, попробуйте узнать какая разрядность у вашей версии python`a, если это x64 попробуйте откатить до 32 битной, если у вас 32 битная уже стоит, а проблема так и не решилась попробуйте вот это :

[Решение проблемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1286876/429303)